# Jquery Multiple actions one if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code..

```
    function showNext(opt)  {
        takeAway();
        if(opt == "Picked Up") $("#pickedup").css("display", "");
        if(opt == "Bus to alternate") $("#altad2").css("display", "");
        if(opt == "Walk to alternate") $("#altad1").css("display", "");
    }


function takeAway(){
    $("#pickedup").css("display", "none");
    $("#altad2").css("display", "none");
    $("#altad1").css("display", "none");
}
```

In this case if someone chooses Bus to alternate or Walk to alternate it would display altad2 and altad1 respectively

But that is not what I want..

What i would like is if someone selects bus to alternate it displays both altad2 and altad1 and same if someone were to choose walk to alternate.

is there an easy way to do something like

```
 if(opt == "Bus to alternate") $("#altad2").css("display", "") and $("#altad1").css("display", "");
    if(opt == "Walk to alternate") $("#altad1").css("display", "") and $("#altad2").css("display", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to do is to create a map it will reduce code size and get faster.

```
function showNext(opt)  {
        takeAway()

      var optMap={
             "Picked Up":"#pickedup",
             "Bus to alternate":"#altad2,#altad1",
             "Walk to alternate":"#altad2,#altad1",
              }
           $(optMap[opt]).css("display","") ;       

}
function takeAway(){
    $("#pickedup,#altad2,#altad1").css("display", "none");
 }
```

Keep all id in one selector as comma seperated . in this it will only create one jquery object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
if(opt == "Bus to alternate" || opt == "Walk to alternate" ){
    $('[id^="altad"]').css("display", "");
}
```

Comment: this would depend upon if any other id is also named "altad" but this is the best solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showNext(opt)    {
takeAway();

if(opt == "Picked Up") $("#pickedup").css("display", "");
if(opt == "Bus to alternate") 
{
 $("#altad2").css("display", "");
 $("#altad1").css("display", "");
}
if(opt == "Walk to alternate") 
{
 $("#altad2").css("display", "");
 $("#altad1").css("display", "");

} 


}
```

Saludos ;)